# had in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

When I use had in the beginning of a sentence, can I use was/were as well?
for instance:
Had I were at home, I would...
Had it was someone else, he was...

for some reason it doesn't sound quite right, but english isn't my native tongue so...

Answer (score 5):

Had you put the word *had* in its ordinary place, would you have used *was* / *were*?

> I had were home.

No, that's wrong (and terrible).  You would write

> I had been home.

So you write:

> Had I been home, I would have answered the door.

Answer (score -2):

In a conditional sentence "were" can be also be used as follows.

If I were in your place,... or, If I were you....I'd return the book.

If you weren't afraid of spiders, you would have picked it up and put it outside.